# "Subscript out of Range" when attempting to copy worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Copy Before:=Workbooks(link.Value).Worksheets("Contract")
End Sub
```

This is the I am 100% sure that link and ComboBox1 have the values that I'm looking for.

Can someone tell me why I keep getting the error "*Subscript out of Range*"?

Comment: If you're using variables as parameters, you don't add the `.value` after.

Comment: @findwindow They aren't variables. One is a ComboBox, one is a TextBox.

Comment: @Davesexcel link is the file the user browses to. So it'll be something like C:\users\me\etc\Test.xls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from:

```
Before := Workbooks(link.Value)
```

From your comments it appears that `link.value` holds the full path name of the file. The method `Workbooks(somename)` needs the *somename* to be a name, such as `Workbooks(test.xls)`, without the path.

Try to get the file name without a path from the browse dialog and feed it to this function without the path. Eventually, to fix it fast, you can use this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Copy Before:=Workbooks(Right(link.Value, Len(link.Value) - InStrRev(link.Value, "\"))).Worksheets("Contract")
```

The added code extracts the file name from the full path given in link.value.

Comment: Now I'm getting a different, very long, error. "Excel cannot insert the sheets into the destination workbook, because it contains fewer rows or columns than the source workbook...."

Comment: This means it was fixed, but you have another error. I think it deserves a question on its own, it is totally another (interesting) issue! :)

Comment: I actually figured out that piece of code after you told me I needed the filename.

Comment: You just want another question so you can have 2 accepted answers, don't you?

Comment: Not at all, really. But it seems to me that you have a really different issue here.! I am not even sure I can really help in it, but I will try :)

Comment: Remember that SO is daily used by many people browsing for issues that they encounter, so it would be better if we repertoriate the issues correctly.

Comment: I know, it was just a joke. I guess those work better when they end with "lol"